# Generators of coprime ideals perfect powers

Tags: number-theory

Could you please help with this a practice exam problem?: Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-22})$ with unit group $\mathcal{O}_k^\times=\{ \pm 1 \}.$ Suppose that  $x,y,z\in\mathcal{O}_K$ are non-zero, satisfy $xy=z^5$ and $(x) + (y) = (1).$ Deduce that $x,y$ are perfect 5th powers, i.e., there are $\alpha,\beta\in\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $x=\alpha^5,y=\beta^5.$ I am supposed to use the fact that the class number of $K$ is $2$.

My guess is that the class number being $2$ implies that $(z^5)\not\sim (1),$ so $(y)\neq (x)^{-1}.$ Then, $\text{gcd}((x),(y))=1$ should imply that $z=\alpha\beta,$ so  $x=\alpha^5,y=\beta^5.$ Is this at all on track? I am not sure about the connection between the class number and the coprimality of the ideals $(x),(y).$

Answer (score 1):

Show that $$(z,x)^5=(x)$$
and deduce that $(z,x)$ is principal.